# GWT - Displayed date is decremented one day

Tags: java, gwt

The server I use is in Melbourne, Australia. I have reports from Perth, Australia that the date displayed is decremented by one day (i.e., 2003-10-31 is displayed as 2003-10-30). In my readings I find that I need to set the time zone. They say do not use the two/three letter time zone use the full time zone. However, I can not find the full time zone for Melbourne, Australia. Can anyone help with this please?

The code I have come up with is:

```
//Display the DOB
DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd australiaMelbourne");
String stringDOB = fmt.format(ythMmbrSectDtls.getDob());
Label dateLblDOB = new Label(stringDOB);
dateLblDOB.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
dateLblDOB.setWidth("100px");
flexTable.setWidget(row, 3, dateLblDOB);
```

The code should be (on the server side):

```
 while (result.next()) {

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(result.getDate("dob"));
                TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
                calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);
                java.sql.Date javaSqlDateDOB = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

                VenturerSectDtls venturerSectDtls = new VenturerSectDtls(
                        result.getString("cdID"), 
                        null, 
                        result.getString("surname"), 
                        result.getString("firstName"),
                        javaSqlDateDOB,
                        //result.getDate("dob"),
```

Answer (score 1):

The full time zone format is `Continent/City` so in your case `Australia/Melbourne`.

For further Information see: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Comment: Hi Akunosh, Have added the code I think I should use. Could you please check this. I think instead of setting the timezone to Australia/Melbourne I should use TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault(); to get the server's time zone (is that what you mean, in your example, by "the system (computer) this program is running on"?). In this way if the program is moved to another server I do not need to change the code. I can not replicate this on my test PC and I do not want to put issues into production. So a desk check would be appreciated.

Comment: I have done more research and I find that this should be done on the server side not the client side. Is that correct? This would work best for me as fixing the date before I pass it through to the client side would mean less changes. Which means I need to ask a new question as I can not find out how to actually do this on the sever side.

Comment: The `TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();` sets the timezone to the default of the operating system where this code/the jvm is running. Meaning if you have this in your client software it will set the timezone to that of the clients computer.
The question is what you want to do with the displayed time. If it is related to the data on the server, like forum entries or a change log or something like that,  then you should use the servers time and send it along to the client, every user gets the same reference.

Comment: Hi Akunosh, Sorry can not understand what you mean. If the date stored is "20160331" then I want "20160331" displayed in Sydney, Adelaide, Perth, Hawaii, everywhere. So should I use TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault(); or TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(Australia/Melbourne); and change it if I change server location. I have also edited the quest as I think I have worked out how to do this on the server side. Is this correct please? I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you want the server-time displayed on each client independent of the clients time zone then requesting this time from the server is the correct way to do it. And if the operating system on the server knows its own location/timezone then .getDefault() will do just fine.

I would however recomment to use a universal time instead of the local time of the server. Especially when this server is supposed to move from time to time and the clientel is international.
When you move the server however you then have to change the time zone setting in the os.

Comment: Hi Akunosh, I have tried both TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault(); and TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"); on the server side in production and neither works.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`SimpleDateFormat`** instead of **`DateTimeFormat`**

**`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);`**

Please check the documentation for SimpleDateFormat here

Java 6 : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Java 7 : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: You can't use `SimpleDateFormat` on the client side of GWT. It's not part of the [JRE Emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).